# Android XML: SIMPLE bottom border for TextView

Tags: android-layout

I have scanned the internet a many times only to find posts which result is complicated settings.

What is the most simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Easy and simple.

Create a nine patch drawable. Fortunately, I have something ready for you:

[image: bottom border as a nine patch for Android layouts]

Save that image. You should learn about [nine patch drawables](http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2010/06/9-patches/) if you don't understand which concepts are applied to this image (I mean, the reason behind those small black bars at the sides).

Save this image as a png ending in `.9.png`. Note the point-9-point-png extension. Let's say you save this as `grey_border_inset_bottom.9.png`. Then, go to your `TextView` and set this:

```
android:background="@drawable/grey_border_inset_bottom"
```

Done. Bottom border.